# Mui Text Input losing focus as soon as I type

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've seen various solutions to this issue online, but I can't figure out how it applies to my situation.  I'm setting up a form in a React app; the form looks like this (I've removed some irrelevant stuff, including the Submit button, to keep it short):

NOTE: I'VE UPDATED THIS - SEE BELOW

```
interface FormState {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

const EnterDetails = () => {
  const [formState, setFormState] = React.useState<FormState>({
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
  });

  const onChangeText = (fieldName: string, newValue: any) => {
    const newFormState = { ...formState };
    newFormState[fieldName] = newValue.target.value;
    setFormState(newFormState);
  };

  return (
      <Box>
        <FormRow>
          <My_TextField
            label="First name"
            value={formState.firstName}
            onChange={(v) => onChangeText('firstName', v)}
          />
          <My_TextField
            label="Surname"
            value={formState.lastName}
            onChange={(v) => onChangeText('lastName', v)}
          />
        </FormRow>
      </Box>
  );
};

export default EnterDetails;
```

`FormRow` and `My_TextField` are defined as follows (`styled`, `Box`, `Typography` etc are imported from `@mui/material`):

```
const StyledRow = styled(Box)(() => ({
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    justifyContent: 'stretch',
    width: '100%',
}));

const FormRow = ({ children }: { children: any }) => {

  return <StyledRow>{children}</StyledRow>;
};

export default FormRow;
```

and

```
const BootstrapLabel = styled(InputLabel)(({ theme }) => ({
  color: theme.palette.mainText.main,
}));

const BootstrapInput = styled(InputBase)(({ theme }) => ({
  color: theme.palette.altText.main,
}));

const My_TextField= ({
  label,
  value,
  onChange,
}: IProps) => {
  return (
    <Box>
      <BootstrapLabel shrink={false}>{label}</BootstrapLabel>
      <FormControl>
        <BootstrapInput
          value={value}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
      </FormControl>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default My_TextField;
```

The form looks fine, but when I try to enter text in one of the fields, it will only take one character at a time - after every one, it loses focus, so I have to click back into the input field to type the next one.

In the solutions I've seen online, people have mentioned that this problem occurs when one Component is defined within another, but I can't see where I've done that, unless I'm not understanding it properly.  Any advice is appreciated.

UPDATE: I've stripped everything back, so now it's all in one component, which is:

```
const EnterDetails = () => {
  const [formState, setFormState] = React.useState({
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
  });

  const onChange = (fieldName: string, newValue: any) => {
    const newState = { ...formState };
    newState[fieldName] = newValue.target.value;
    setFormState({ ...newState });
  };

  const PageWrapper = styled(Box)(({ theme }) => ({
    marginTop: theme.spacing(4),
    marginLeft: 'auto',
    marginRight: 'auto',
    textAlign: 'center',
    maxWidth: '800px',
  }));

  return (
        <PageWrapper>
          <BootstrapInput
            required={true}
            value={formState.firstName}
            onChange={(v) => onChange('firstName', v)}
          />
          <BootstrapInput
            required={true}
            value={formState.lastName}
            onChange={(v) => onChange('lastName', v)}
          />
        </PageWrapper>
  );
};

export default EnterDetails;
```

This has the same issue - the input boxes lose focus once a single character is typed.

However, if I replace `PageWrapper` with `Box`, it works.  I don't understand why applying the styling to turn `Box` into `PageWrapper` is causing it to lose focus?  Obviously I can just use `Box`, but I want to understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because every time `formState` is updated `EnterDetails` rerender and return a new `<FormRow>` so it loses focus, what you have to do is to make only `<FormRow>` render with putting `formState` inside it:

```
const StyledRow = styled(Box)(() => ({
  display: "flex",
  flexDirection: "row",
  flexWrap: "wrap",
  justifyContent: "stretch",
  width: "100%",
}));

const FormRow = () => {
  const [formState, setFormState] =
    React.useState <
    FormState >
    {
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
    };

  const onChangeText = (fieldName: string, newValue: any) => {
    const newFormState = { ...formState };
    newFormState[fieldName] = newValue.target.value;
    setFormState(newFormState);
  };
  return (
    <StyledRow>
      <My_TextField
        label="First name"
        value={formState.firstName}
        onChange={(v) => onChangeText("firstName", v)}
      />
      <My_TextField
        label="Surname"
        value={formState.lastName}
        onChange={(v) => onChangeText("lastName", v)}
      />
    </StyledRow>
  );
};

export default FormRow;
```

and form EnterDetails jsx :

```
return (
  <Box>
    //...
    <FormRow/>
    //...
  </Box>
);
```